# Htaccess regex for trats

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Urls:

http://www.gamempire.it/hello-pc

http://www.gamempire.it/hello-ps3

I want to 301 them to: http://www.gamempire.it/hello

but this doesn't work: `RewriteRule ^(.*)-(pc|ps3)(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]`

Thanks

Comment: Elaborate on "doesn't work". What does happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to capture `$2` and use it in replacement.

You can use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-(?:pc|ps3)(.*)$ /$1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can use `.` instead of `[^-]`, and IMO it's easier to read

Comment: Yes that will work also but just for efficiency factor I used negation `[^-]`

Comment: ps: i need the `$2` because the url could be `http://www.gamempire.it/hello-pc/second-section`

Comment: @anubhava why this `([^-]*)` and not this `(.*)` ?

Comment: Mostly of efficiency purpose. `[^-]*` is processed without backtracking in regex engines.